# Comma separated string to JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I need to update/migrate a table `IdsTable` in my SQL Server database which has the following format:

```
+----+------------------+---------+
| id |       ids        | idType  |
+----+------------------+---------+
|  1 | id11, id12, id13 | idType1 |
|  2 | id20             | idType2 |
+----+------------------+---------+
```

The `ids` column is a comma separate list of ids. I need to combine the `ids` and `idType` column to form a single JSON string for each row and update the `ids` column with that object.

The JSON object has the following format:

```
{
   "idType": string,
   "ids": string[]
}
```

Final table after transforming/migrating data should be:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id |                         ids                         | idType  |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | {"idType": "idType1","ids": ["id11","id12","id13"]} | idType1 |
|  2 | {"idType": "idType2","ids": ["id20"]}               | idType2 |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

The best I've figured out so far is to get the results into a format where I could `GROUP BY id` to try and get the correct JSON format:

```
SELECT X.id, Y.value, X.idType
FROM 
    IdsTable AS X 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(X.ids, ',') AS Y
```

Which gives me the results:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | ids  | idType  |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | id11 | idType1 |
|  1 | id12 | idType1 |
|  1 | id13 | idType1 |
|  2 | id20 | idType2 |
+----+------+---------+
```

But I'm not familiar enough with SQL Server JSON to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [blog post](https://bertwagner.com/2017/12/19/how-to-create-json-multi-object-arrays-in-sql-server/) that helped me construct my answer:

```
-- Create Temporary Table
SELECT 
    [TAB].[id], [TAB].[ids],
    (
        SELECT [STRING_SPLIT_RESULTS].value as [ids], [TAB].[idType] as [idType]
        FROM [IdsTable] AS [REQ] 
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([REQ].[ids],',') AS [STRING_SPLIT_RESULTS]
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) as [newIds]
INTO [#TEMP_RESULTS]
FROM [IdsTable] AS [TAB] 

-- Update rows
UPDATE [IdsTable]
SET [ids] = [#TEMP_RESULTS].[newIds]  
FROM [#TEMP_RESULTS]
WHERE [IdsTable].[Id] = [#TEMP_RESULTS].[Id]

-- Delete Temporary Table
DROP TABLE [#TEMP_RESULTS]
```

Which replaces those `ids` column (not replaced below for comparison):

```
+----+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |      ids       | idType  |                                                newIds                                                |
+----+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | id11,id12,id13 | idType1 | [{"id":"id11","idType":"idType1"},{"id":"id12","idType":"idType1"},{"id":"id13","idType":"idType1"}] |
|  2 | id20           | idType2 | [{"id":"id20","idType":"idType2"}]                                                                   |
+----+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is more verbose that I wanted but considering the table size and the number of ids stored in the `ids` column which translates to the size of the JSON object, this is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-off op I think I'd just do it the dirty way:

```
UPDATE table SET ids = 
  CONCAT('{"idType": "', idType, '","ids": ["', REPLACE(ids, ', ', '","'), '"]}'
```

You might need to do some prep first, like if your `ids` column can look like:

```
id1,id2,id3
id4, id5,  id6
id7 ,id8 , id9
```

etc, a series of replacements like:

```
UPDATE table SET ids = REPLACE(ids, ' ,', ',') WHERE ids LIKE '% ,%'
UPDATE table SET ids = REPLACE(ids, ', ', ',') WHERE ids LIKE '%, %'
```

Keep running those until they don't update any more records

ps; if you've removed all the spaces from around the commas, you'll need to tweak the REPLACE in the original query - I specified `', '` as the needle